# http post in loop is running timing out

Tags: php

I am trying to send curl request from source to destination in loop. Loop runs for 2 times. First request lasts for 32 seconds and second one for 50 seconds. Finally times out. Controlling timeout is not in my control as it is shared hosting.

Source section below is being run in the browser. the below error message shows after using up 120 seconds

> Error Details: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds
> exceeded

**Question**
I am assuming that the request should not timeout, since both requests are submitted separately through their own curl request. Still, it seems like it is getting consolidated to form total one request.

In case I run the loop for one time, then everything works as it takes 30 seconds.

Am I missing anything?

**Source**

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 200; $i+= 100) {
    $postData = array(
        'start' => $i,
        'end' => $i + 100
    );

    $ch = curl_init('Server url');
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postData)
    ));
    
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $responseData = json_decode($response, TRUE);
    curl_close($ch);
    
    echo $response;
}
```

**Destination**

```
public function methodname()
{
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    // .
    // .
    // Logic that runs for 32 seconds
    // .
    // . 
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode("message");
}
```

Comment: It’s not clear what the problem is (please edit to clarify) - but why not emit the requests in parallel using curl multi? How are you invoking “source”? Cli or a http request?

Comment: This question is too broad :). I say that because it fails after 2 requests, and it sounds like there is no possibility of emitting 200 http requests to destination and having them all complete in 120s (definitely not if you emit them serially as is the case in the question). The only possibility is to emit them in parallel (curl multi) but it’s implied in the question this will overwhelm “destination”.

Comment: Alternatively the process needs redesigning - such as to use a job queue

Comment: Do these API calls take so much time? Can you speed them up, by optimizing the endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

try using cURl's CURLOPT_TIMEOUT or similar configurations. More information https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php here

Answer: read the documentation

LE:

You could also use set_time_limit(0); // or value > 120 to increase your script execution timeout

Comment: Same issue after adding `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`

Comment: set a timeout on your script - maybe the main script times out before it completely executes - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: sure - in your php script you neet to set a time limit

```

set_time_limit(0); // or a value higher than 120

```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a `sleep(1)` function inner your loop. It could be that the server which you are requested dont like multiple POST request in a short time.

Comment: If 200 API calls occur, and each one uses `sleep(1)`, this needs already 200 seconds for all sleep calls. If PHP already throws "Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded", this cannot be resolved by slowing down the execution further

Comment: @NicoHaase Thank you for you feedback. it is only 20 request and not 200. take a look to the incrementing part of the for loop. the timeout does not refer to the sum of all curl requests but to the individual ones. unfortunately i have to disagree with you today. even if it is difficult for me ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I misread that! And please: disagree with me whenever you need it ;)

Comment: @NicoHaase I will do that ;-) bye

Comment: Nonetheless: if PHP throws that error for a fully consumed max execution time, this depends on the sum of cURL requests, as this counter is not reset between cURL calls

Comment: @NicoHaase Ok. that's useful information. can you give me the source of the info please.

Comment: Source of which information? Something like https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php?